# How do I get the output value of an async method as input and display using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nodes

I am a bit new to node and express

I am trying to build an API that consumes an external API and returns the result as input to what I display

How do I get the output value of an async method as input and display using the express send method

see my express code below

```
const express = require("express");
var AsyncMethod = require("./src/AsyncMethod");//works perfectly
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.get("/url", (req, res) => {
var output = "";
  var biller = new AsyncMethod();
  try {
    output = await (biller.run());
    .then(//need help here
      console.log("inside Main")
    res.send(output))
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log("An error occurred");
    res.send("An error occurred");
    console.log(ex);
  }
});
```

Comment: if you `await` you don't need `.then` ... especially like you've written it ... `output` will have the result of `biller.run()` (whatever that resolves to)

Comment: The problem is nothing is being returned to postman when we get on 127.0.0.1:8000/url

Comment: I'm surprised the code is running with that random `.then( .... )` - that's a syntax error right there that will stop the code from running at all

Comment: Or are you saying that `output` is empty ... perhaps `biller.run();` doesn't return a Promise that you can `await`

Comment: we'd probably need to see what `./src/AsyncMethod` is doing, specifically the `.run` method

Comment: can you  your github userid so i can add you to the project

Comment: Absolutely not - how about this ... is `run` an `async` function? OR, does `run` return a `Promise`? If you answered *no* to both of these, then your issue is in the code you haven't shown

Comment: One moment while I check,

Comment: its neither
see the project here. >> https://github.com/techlinesolutions/autosync

Comment: So, what DOES biller.run() return?

Comment: it returns>>>
[
  {
    categoryid: '1',
    categoryname: 'Utility Bills',
    categorydescription: 'Pay your utility bills here'
  },
  {
    categoryid: '2',
    categoryname: 'Cable TV Bills',
    categorydescription: 'Pay for y......

Comment: well, no need to `await` it then - maybe that's the issue, you're awaiting in a function that isn't async - you'd get an error on the server side for sure

Comment: I removed the await, the problem still persists, there's no output in postman

Comment: I never said removing await is the solution - the solution is in fixing `biller.run` - the problem is, biller as an instance of `require("./src/AsyncMethod")` - sure, you've posted some github link ... without that module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the github project you posted a link to in the comment

`.run` needs to return a `Promise` if you want to `await` it

So - here's how to do that ... the 5 additional lines are marked `//+++`

```
var BaseSample = require('./BaseSample');

var GetBillers = function(){
    //inherit
    BaseSample.call(this);
}

GetBillers.prototype.run = function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  //+++
    this.billpayment.get_billers(function(err, res){
        if(err) {
            //error executing request
            console.log("Error calling get billers "+JSON.stringify(err));
            reject(err); //+++
        } else{
            //check if it was successful
            var statusCode = res.statusCode;

            if(statusCode === 200) {//request was successful

                var billerArray = JSON.parse(res.body).billers;
                var firstBiller = billerArray[0];

                var billerId = firstBiller.billerid;
                var billername = firstBiller.billername;
                console.log(billerId+" "+billername);
                resolve(billerId+" "+billername); //+++
            }
            else{//it was not successful for a reason
                console.log("FAILED: "+statusCode);
                reject(statusCode); //+++
            }
        }
    });
  }); //+++
}

module.exports = GetBillers;
```

Oh, and the code you posted should look a bit like

```
const express = require("express");
var AsyncMethod = require("./src/AsyncMethod");//works perfectly
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.get("/url", (req, res) => {
  var biller = new AsyncMethod();
  try {
    const output = await biller.run();
    console.log("inside Main")
    res.send(output))
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log("An error occurred");
    res.send("An error occurred");
    console.log(ex);
  }
});
```

Comment: My friend, you are truly a genius. Thanks so much, everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait for async method execution to completed by using the `.then()` method and return the response from the callback.

**Using `Async/Await`**

```
const express = require("express");
var AsyncMethod = require("./src/AsyncMethod");//works perfectly
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.get("/url", async (req, res) => {
    var output = "";
    var biller = new AsyncMethod();
    try {
        output = await biller.run();
        res.send(output)
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log("An error occurred");
      res.send("An error occurred");
      console.log(ex);
    }

});
```

**Using `promise`**

```
const express = require("express");
var AsyncMethod = require("./src/AsyncMethod");//works perfectly
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.get("/url", (req, res) => {
    var biller = new AsyncMethod();
    biller.run().then(function(output){
      res.send(output)
    }).catch(function(ex){
      console.log("An error occurred");
      res.send("An error occurred");
      console.log(ex);
    })
});
```

Comment: your answer is OK, but your first sentence is completely misleading

Comment: Hey Pal, thanks for the code snippet, The problem is nothing is being returned to postman when we get on http://127.0.0.1:8000/url

Comment: perhaps `biller.run()` doesn't return a Promise that you can await? what does `console.log(output)` output (on the server, of course)

Comment: console.log(output) returns undefined